# getting error when using FirebaseRecyclerView, No static method zza(Landroid/app/Application;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzaac;

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio-2.3

I am making a blog app using Firebase for Android.
But I am getting an error when application starts. My code is fully right, but I am still getting this error.

Here is the catlog error

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zza(Landroid/app/Application;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzaac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaac' appears in /data/app/com.a000webhostapp.androidgrid.devtips-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzcl(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5384)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here's my model Blog.java

```
public class Blog {

private String title;
private String desc;


public Blog(){

}

public Blog(String title, String desc) {
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
```

}

Here's my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recycleView;
private DatabaseReference fDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

    recycleView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyleView);
    recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
            Blog.class,
            R.layout.post_list_layout,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            fDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());

        }
    };

    recycleView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtBlogTitle);

        post_title.setText(title);

    }

    public void setDesc(String desc){
        TextView post_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtBlogDesc);

        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }

}
```

}

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Do change all the `firebase` and `Google-play-services` library versions to the same in your `dependencies` under `app.gradle` file.